# yii cgridview filter by function on the model

Tags: php, yii, cgridview

I am trying to use a Cgridview In yii to show rows from a table.

This table refers the model A.
The problem is that this model has a function getState() that returns a value for that particular row.

I need to only show rows based on the return value of this function.
I cannot just put the condition in conditions on CActiveProvider, as it's not a simple SQL condition. I need to use the output of getState().

Is there any simple way to do this ?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Not tested, try to extend CActiveDataProvider, override "fetchData()" and "calculateTotalItemCount()" functions accordingly.